# Ubuntu Server 64bit 11.04: setting up as "Ruby on Rails" server with SQLite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu-11.04

I have looked so long for nice tutorials, but still couldn't find any for Ubuntu 11.04. I wan't to set it up to learn by this book: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

The tutorials I found are not quite up to date and also doesn't aren't for 11.04 Ubuntu.

I am asking for quick tutorial, what's the best way to set up RoR server.

Also if you know any other great Ruby on Rails tutorials, as the link I wrote above, please don't hold back and definitely share the link to it.

Ty in advance!

PS! I already messed up one of my Virtual Machines, but luckily I had made snapshot of clean install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu has Rails packages already. It should be as simple as doing `apt-get install rails-ruby1.8`, which'll install Ruby as a dependency as well.

Comment: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book
Used the link above, the one I actually already mentioned in my question. Followed the environment setup there and works nicely!

Answer (score 0):

[Ryan Bigg](http://ryanbigg.com) has a very nice tutorial called [Ubuntu, Ruby, RVM, Rails and You](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/). Since you're configuring a server you will probably have a look at some [tips about deployment & best practices](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/deployment/best-practices/) written by the creator of RVM himself.

I'm sure you have it done already though since it's an old question, but I the links will be of use to someone else.